# Count the number of times an index is a specific name in an array php

Tags: php

I am trying to count the number of times a value exists in a specific index in an array.

e.g. These are values returned in a while statement from MySQL.

```
Array ( [1] => Yes [2] => No [3] => No [id] => 1 )
Array ( [1] => No [2] => No [3] => Yes [id] => 1 )
Array ( [1] => No [2] => No [3] => No [id] => 1 )
```

[X] value can either be Yes or No.

[X] (# of indexes) is dynamic.

I need a total of how many Yes and No values appear in each index.

Using this code I can get a count of all Yes values, but it is for the entire array.

```
$total_yes = array_count_values($proposals);
$sum_yes = $sum_yes + $total_yes['Yes'];
```

During the loop (while), I need to know the # of Yes and No for each index and have a cumulative total at the end of the loop.

Based on the sample arrays, this is what I would like to know:

Total Yes values for [1]: 1 , Total No values for [1]: 2

Total Yes values for [2]: 0 , Total No values for [2]: 3

Total Yes values for [3]: 1 , Total No values for [3]: 2

And since [X] is dynamic, how would I know the # of indexes to create the totals for?

I hope this make sense and is possible. I've looked through the answers but could not find anything that would help.

Comment: Checkout the [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) function. Keep in mind it was introduced in PHP 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my approach:

```
$Array[] =array( '1' => 'Yes', '2' => 'No', '3' => 'No', 'id' => '1' );
$Array[] =array( '1' => 'No', '2' => 'No', '3' => 'Yes', 'id' => '1' );
$Array[] =array( '1' => 'No', '2' => 'No', '3' => 'No', 'id' => '1' );



$totals = array();
foreach ($Array as $a){
    foreach ($a as $k=>$v){
        if (is_numeric($k)){ //will exclude non numeric keys such as id in this case
            if (! isset($totals[$k]['No'])){
                $totals[$k]['No'] = $totals[$k]['yes'] = 0; // set starting values to 0 before first loop
            }
            if ($v == 'Yes'){

                $totals[$k]['yes'] ++;
            }elseif ($v == 'No'){
                $totals[$k]['No'] ++;
            }
        }
    }
}



print_r($totals);
```

output:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [yes] => 1
        [No] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [yes] => 0
        [No] => 3
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [yes] => 1
        [No] => 2
    )
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks Dagon!

Comment: @user2413654 tweak so you get a yes no 0 count in the array (before 0 was just blank) and excluded id

Comment: Thanks again. This makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($proposals as $key=>$element){
    if($element == 'Yes'){
        $yes[$key]++;
    } else if($element == 'No'){
        $no[$key]++;
    }
}
print_r($yes);
print_r($no);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to do it with the accepted answer.